# Capacitive-divider high-voltage adapter

Tags: voltage-divider, high-voltage

I am reading a paper about the high voltage adapter. This paper uses the capacitive biasing method to make the transistors not be overstressed. VDVS seems to follow the VE. C1-CN-1 is used to divide the high voltage. But how can I choose the size of the capacitors to divide the high voltage? It seems that capacitors can't divide DC voltage.

Paper: E. Pepin, J. Uehlin, D. Micheletti, S. I. Perlmutter and J. C. Rudell, **"A high-voltage compliant, electrode-invariant neural stimulator front-end in 65nm bulk-CMOS,"** *ESSCIRC Conference 2016: 42nd European Solid-State Circuits Conference*, Lausanne, Switzerland, 2016, pp. 229-232, doi: 10.1109/ESSCIRC.2016.7598284. ([University of Washington download link](https://labs.ece.uw.edu/fast/papers/201603.pdf))

[image: High-voltage adapter (HVA) circuit schematic and control summary]

Comment: pumpkinxs - (a) Thanks for adding the DOI number. From that I found the full citation and download link, and added them for you. For the future, please remember that it's your responsibility to do that i.e. to add a correct [reference / citation](/help/referencing) for any copied or adapted material you put onto the site. (b) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as the site rules here differ from typical forums. || Now that the research paper has been correctly referenced and site members can read it to better understand your question, the question has been reopened.